# Add transparency to overlaid gif on a video using ffmpeg

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to add a vintage kind of effect on the selected video. For the effect, I used a vintage effect gif file and I successfully added it as an overlay on my video using the below method.

```
ffmpeg.execute(new String[]{"-i",uri,"-ignore_loop", "1","-i",overlayUri ,"-filter_complex","[0:v]scale="+width+":"+height+"[v1];[1:v]scale="+width+":"+height+"[v2];[v1][v2]overlay",outputPath}, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.d("success", "process complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {
                    Log.d("progress", message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.d("failure", message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d("success", "process complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                }
            });
            break;
```

But now as the overlay is not transparent, I can't see the video behind the overlay image. So how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
% ffmpeg -v warning -ss 45 -t 2 -i big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov -vf scale=300:-1 -gifflags -transdiff -y bbb-notrans.gif
% ffmpeg -v warning -ss 45 -t 2 -i big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov -vf scale=300:-1 -gifflags +transdiff -y bbb-trans.gif
% ls -l bbb-*.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 ux ux 1.1M Mar 15 22:50 bbb-notrans.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 ux ux 369K Mar 15 22:50 bbb-trans.gif
```

**Reference link:** 
http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: My end product will be video with a kind of vintage effect applied to the video by overlaying a vintage effect gif with some transparency

Answer (score 0):

After wasting many hours I realised that gifs can't be edited once created. Therefore I opted to overlay another video on top of one video and add transparency to the overlay video.
I also had to resize the overlay video to match the dimensions of the current video.
I achieved it using the following commands

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i", uri,
                    "-i",overlayUri,"-filter_complex","[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1,format=yuva444p,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[u];[b][u]overlay", outputPath};
```

Here **uri** is my original video, **overlayUri** is video that will work as overlay and **outPutPath** is the path where file will be stored.

Although I don't know how the above command actually works but after googling a lot and combining few different commands, I got it working with the above command.

Comment: How to looping overlaid video?
e.g My original video is about 30 sec & overlaid video is 10 sec so how to looping that overlaid video up to 30 sec?

Comment: yes you can loop it. There is command for loop too .I am not good with ffmpeg, but you can find that easily